# Add class to an input when its focused, and remove it when isnt focused

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I'm trying to add the class ".contact__form-input--focused" to the input that is focused from a form.

I'm trying to do that adding an event listener to every input, and then if it has the class already delete that class from the classlist.

```js
//INPUT ANIMATION
const input = document.querySelectorAll("contact__form-input");

function addClass(input) {
  input.classList.add("contact__form-input--focused");
}

function removeClass(input) {
  input.classList.remove("contact__form-input--focused");
}

for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  if (item[i].classList.contains("contact__form-input--focused")) {
    item.addEventListener("focus", addClass(input[i]));
  } else {
    item.addEventListener("blur", removeClass(input[i]));
  }
}
```

```css
.contact__form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.contact__form-input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: .1rem solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
  font-size: var(--medium-font-size);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: 0 0;
  text-align: left;
  color: inherit;
}

.contact__form-input--focused {
  /*some animations here*/
}
```

```html
<form class="contact__form" method="POST">
  <label class="contact__form-label">
            <span>Name</span>
            <input class="contact__form-input" name="Name" type="text" autocomplete="name" required>
          </label>
  <label class="contact__form-label">
            <span>Phone number</span>
            <input class="contact__form-input" name="Phone number" type="tel" autocomplete="tel" required>
          </label>
  <label class="contact__form-label">
            <span>Message</span>
            <input class="contact__form-input" type="text" required>
          </label>
  <button class="contact__form-button">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: why not just use a [:focus CSS pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** You are not getting the HTML elements because `contact__form-input` is a class and you have to tell `querySelectorAll` that you are looking for all elements whose class is `contact__form-input` by appending `.` before className

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll( ".contact__form-input" );
```

**2)** You should add `eventListener` on `focus` or `blur` as:

```
inputs.forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener("focus", () => addClass(input))
  input.addEventListener("blur", () => removeClass(input))
})
```

**`NOTE: For demo purpose I've added thick red border`**

```js
//INPUT ANIMATION
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".contact__form-input");

function addClass(input) {
  input.classList.add("contact__form-input--focused");
}

function removeClass(input) {
  input.classList.remove("contact__form-input--focused");
}

console.log(inputs)

inputs.forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener("focus", () => addClass(input))
  input.addEventListener("blur", () => removeClass(input))
})
```

```css
.contact__form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.contact__form-input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: .1rem solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
  font-size: var(--medium-font-size);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: 0 0;
  text-align: left;
  color: inherit;
}

.contact__form-input--focused {
  /*some animations here*/
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form class="contact__form" method="POST">
  <label class="contact__form-label">
            <span>Name</span>
            <input class="contact__form-input" name="Name" type="text" autocomplete="name" required>
          </label>
  <label class="contact__form-label">
            <span>Phone number</span>
            <input class="contact__form-input" name="Phone number" type="tel" autocomplete="tel" required>
          </label>
  <label class="contact__form-label">
            <span>Message</span>
            <input class="contact__form-input" type="text" required>
          </label>
  <button class="contact__form-button">Send</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

if your using JS like this and not just the pseudo of `:focus` you can do it by

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("contact__form-input");
inputs.forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener("focus", function(){
        this.classList.add("contact__form-input--focused");
    });
    input.addEventListener("blur", function(){
        this.classList.remove("contact__form-input--focused");
    });
});
```

Or if you want to switch the classes

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("contact__form-input");
function switchInputClasses(){
    this.classList.toggle("contact__form-input");
    this.classList.toggle("contact__form-input--focused");
}
inputs.forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener("focus", switchInputClasses);
    input.addEventListener("blur", switchInputClasses);
});
```

The reason for functions declarations and not `()=>{}` is because the latter will preserve scope and to set up the `this` keyword correctly you need the scopes to be changed, the best way to think of it is an `EventListner` is called via `apply()` on the element

The pseudo method is just change your CSS to be

```css
.contact__form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.contact__form-input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: .1rem solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
  font-size: var(--medium-font-size);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: 0 0;
  text-align: left;
  color: inherit;
}

.contact__form-input:focus {
  /*some animations here*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `if` statement. Just add both event listeners to all the inputs.

The 2nd argument to `addEventListener()` must be a function. You're calling the function immediately, not when the event happens.

```js
//INPUT ANIMATION
const input = document.querySelectorAll(".contact__form-input");

function addClass(input) {
  input.classList.add("contact__form-input--focused");
}

function removeClass(input) {
  input.classList.remove("contact__form-input--focused");
}

for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  let item = input[i];
  item.addEventListener("focus", () => addClass(item));
  item.addEventListener("blur", () => removeClass(item));
}
```

```css
.contact__form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.contact__form-input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: .1rem solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
  font-size: var(--medium-font-size);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: 0 0;
  text-align: left;
  color: inherit;
}

.contact__form-input--focused {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<form class="contact__form" method="POST">
  <label class="contact__form-label">
            <span>Name</span>
            <input class="contact__form-input" name="Name" type="text" autocomplete="name" required>
          </label>
  <label class="contact__form-label">
            <span>Phone number</span>
            <input class="contact__form-input" name="Phone number" type="tel" autocomplete="tel" required>
          </label>
  <label class="contact__form-label">
            <span>Message</span>
            <input class="contact__form-input" type="text" required>
          </label>
  <button class="contact__form-button">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Selecting without `.` in `querySelectorAll`. Isn't the statement should be `document.querySelectorAll( ".contact__form-input" );`

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
    .contact__form {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .contact__form-input {
        border: none;
        border-bottom: .1rem solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
        font-size: var(--medium-font-size);
        margin: 0;
        padding: 4px 0;
        width: 100%;
        background: 0 0;
        text-align: left;
        color: inherit;
    }

    .contact__form-input--focused {
        /*some animations here*/
    }
</style>

<form class="contact__form" method="POST">
    <label class="contact__form-label">
        <span>Name</span>
        <input class="contact__form-input" name="Name" type="text" autocomplete="name">
    </label>
    <label class="contact__form-label">
        <span>Phone number</span>
        <input class="contact__form-input" name="Phone" type="tel" autocomplete="tel" required>
    </label>
    <label class="contact__form-label">
        <span>Message</span>
        <input class="contact__form-input" name="Text" type="Text" required>
    </label>
    <button class="contact__form-button">Send</button>
</form>

<script>
    const inputName = document.querySelector("input[name=Name]");
    const inputPhone = document.querySelector("input[name=Phone]");
    const inputText = document.querySelector("input[name=Text]");
    inputName.addEventListener("focus", function() {
        if(inputName.classList.contains("contact__form-input--focused"))
            inputName.classList.remove("contact__form-input--focused");
        else
            inputName.classList.add("contact__form-input--focused");
    });
    inputPhone.addEventListener("focus", function() {
        if(inputPhone.classList.contains("contact__form-input--focused"))
            inputPhone.classList.remove("contact__form-input--focused");
        else
            inputPhone.classList.add("contact__form-input--focused");
    });
    inputText.addEventListener("focus", function() {
        if(inputText.classList.contains("contact__form-input--focused"))
            inputText.classList.remove("contact__form-input--focused");
        else
            inputText.classList.add("contact__form-input--focused");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).